# Flutter Provider: Firebase Auth StateChanges is listened but state is not changing

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, provider

I'm currently use Firebase Authentication service on my Flutter project. This project use Provider as its state management. After setting up sign in and sign up services, they are all work well. But as you can see, the `wrapper.dart` file seems to listen the `AuthStateChanges()` method through provider from `main.dart` (as the parent). Even tough it listens, the if else statement inside wrapper doesn't rebuilt if the state changes. Resulting, the homepage doesn't automatically pushed if sign in or sign up method succeded. But, it does indeed work when I hot restart the application.

My objectives is whenever the Sign In process succeed, the wrapper if else statement is listen and obviously rebuild so that the `HomePage()` for instance can be pushed in realtime.

Here's my project repository link on Github: https://github.com/fullstack-dre/packme

Can anybody help me here? Perhaps on how should I implement the providers? Thank you very much.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1):

you need to import first firebase_auth.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Then use `authStateChanges()` not `AuthStateChanges()`

you can authenticate using this code.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```